# How to load WooCommerce before my custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have WooCommerce installed, and I am also building a custom plugin.

My custom plugin is running before WooCommerce because (from what I’ve read) they are loaded Alphabetically (unless using mu-plugin etc).

WooCommerce (when activated) adds a taxonomy: `product_cat` as normal.

My custom plugin has a function which is trying to use that taxonomy, but at this point the custom plugin has loaded before WooCommerce, so the taxonomy `product_cat` does not yet exist.

`wp_set_object_terms( 1118, 41, 'product_cat', true );`

So my error is:
`0 => string ‘Invalid taxonomy.’ (length=17)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a hook that checks if WooCommerce is loaded first, and then execute your function like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'action_woocommerce_loaded', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Today I was debugging a naughty plugin and tried to use this `woocommerce_loaded` event but it didn't work completely. Woocommerce had been started but the main woocommerce instance (from `WC()`) hadn't run it's own `init()` method yet?? So I switched to trigger on the `woocommerce_init` event instead. This is with Woocommerce 6.7.0.